# Gant by example

Tags: groovy, build-script, gant

I am trying to get a simple "Hello, Gant!" Gant build up and running. I just downloaded & extracted the 1.9.10-Groovy-2.0.0 version and am trying to create a build that defines a single `greet` task. When `greet` executes, it prints a "*Hello, Gant!*" message to STDOUT.

Specific questions:

- How do I "install" Gant? Do I need to define any env vars, like `GANT_HOME`, and then put `%GANT_HOME%\bin` on the system `Path`, etc.?
- What do I name my Gant buildscript? Anything I like, such as `HelloGant.groovy`?
- How do I run a `greet` task, defined in `HelloGant.groovy`, from the command-line?

Comment: FYI - none of these questions are answered on the Gant website, or in the downloaded ZIP's `README`.

Comment: [Installation Guide](https://github.com/Gant/Gant/blob/master/README_Install.txt) and  [examples](https://github.com/Gant/Gant/tree/master/examples/testScripts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re: install. Yes, the install is typical. Define `GANT_HOME` and place `GANT_HOME/bin` in `PATH`

The typical Gant build file is `build.gant`. Here is an example that is **not** the default:

```
$ cat HelloGant.groovy 

target ('greet' : 'greet') {
    println "hi there"
}
```

Here is an example execution:

```
$ gant -f HelloGant.groovy greet
greet:
hi there
------ greet

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1.52 seconds
```